# Neo4j cache configurations

Tags: neo4j

I have been playing around with heap size for JVM and the file store cache size in Neo4j. It seems like setting the memory mapped buffer to be handled by the OS does not have any effect on the system.

I tried setting the JVM heap quite large with a tiny cache and it was exactly as fast as a if the cache was large.

So my question is: How can I configure the system to allow me to control the cache? Is this an issue with the batching as it says that this uses the JVM heap?

I am using the following python script to fill up the database

```
neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")

f = open('indexslowdown_exp.txt','w')
f.write("Properties\t,\tSpeed\n")
total_time = timedelta(0)
name = 0
for y in range(0,1000):
    batch = neo4j.WriteBatch(graph_db)
    for x in range(0,100): 
        batch.create({"name":name})
        name += 1
    for x in range(0,100):
        rand_node_A = random.randint(0,name-1)
        rand_node_B = random.randint(0,name-1) 
        batch.append_cypher("START n=node("+str(rand_node_A)+"),    m=node("+str(rand_node_B)+") CREATE (n)-[r:CONNECTED]->(m)")    
    start_time = datetime.now()
    batch.submit()
    end_time = datetime.now()
    total_time = (end_time-start_time)
    f.write(str(name)+" , "+str((total_time)/200)+"\n")
    print "Inserting nodes: " + str(total_time)
f.close()
```

**Neo4j.properties file:**

```
use_memory_mapped_buffers=true

/# Default values for the low-level graph engine
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=1k
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=1k
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=2k
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=1k
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=1k

 # Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version
 #allow_store_upgrade=true

 # Enable this to specify a parser other than the default one.
 #cypher_parser_version=2.0

 # Keep logical logs, helps debugging but uses more disk space, enabled for
 # legacy reasons To limit space needed to store historical logs use values such
 # as: "7 days" or "100M size" instead of "true"
keep_logical_logs=true

 # Autoindexing

 # Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false
 #node_auto_indexing=true

 # The node property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
 #node_keys_indexable=name,age

 # Enable auto-indexing for relationships, default is false
 #relationship_auto_indexing=true

 # The relationship property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
 #relationship_keys_indexable=name,age
```

**neo4j-wrapper:**

```
 wrapper.java.additional=-Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties
 wrapper.java.additional=-Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties
 wrapper.java.additional=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties

 #********************************************************************
 # JVM Parameters
 #********************************************************************

wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled

 # Uncomment the following lines to enable garbage collection logging
wrapper.java.additional=-Xloggc:data/log/neo4j-gc.log
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+PrintGCDetails
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution

 # Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.initmemory=200

 # Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.maxmemory=400

 #********************************************************************
 # Wrapper settings
 #********************************************************************
 # Override default pidfile and lockfile 
 #wrapper.pidfile=../data/neo4j-server.pid
 #wrapper.lockfile=../data/neo4j-server.lck

 #********************************************************************
 # Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
 #********************************************************************
 # WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
 #  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
 #  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
 #  service can then be reinstalled.

 # Name of the service
wrapper.name=neo4j

 # User account to be used for linux installs. Will default to current
 # user if not set.
wrapper.user=
```

Comment: For writing it has not to keep everything in memory-mapping (for many parts you just write data out), for reading it helps much more and if Neo4j has to update random portions of the store it is of course better if they are memory mapped.

Comment: Ok, perfect. That is what I wanted to know. That also makes sense, since I did not see any performance difference in the writing of the nodes and relationships when decreasing the cache size, only when I decreased the heap size. I will accept this as an answer if you write it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What are you most concerned with? Batch insertion performance? If so, MMIO will be most effective if you can fit the entire graph into memory, so if you can estimate the number of nodes and relationships, you can come up with a rough calculation of the size you need for those two stores.

Also given that you look to only be inserting primitives, you can likely estimate the size for the property store that you need.  If you're going to store strings and arrays (of a larger type), you can increase the MMIO settings for those two stores, as well, but if you don't need them, set them low.

Approx. size of node store: # of nodes * 14 bytes (if you're using the latest Neo4j; 9 bytes if Neo4j is < 2.0)

Approx. size of relationship store: # of rels * 33 bytes

Remember: There's a near 1:1 correspondence between the store sizes on disk and in memory for the filesystem cache.

As well, a larger JVM heap doesn't necessarily mean greater performance; in fact, the MMIO sizes (depending on your value for the setting use_memory_mapped_buffers) may lie outside of the JVM heap.  Regardless, a large JVM heap can also introduce longer GC pauses and other GC-related issues, so don't make it too big.

HTH

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I want to do. But I just find it weird that the performance for inserting is exactly the same when I lower the cache to almost nothing for the stores and turn on the memory mapping buffer. It seems like it the memory mapping is not turned on since only the heap is affecting the final performance.

Comment: What kind of times are you getting? Like what's the value of "total_time"?

Also, doing some quick math, it looks like you're doing batches of 100 relationships 1000 times.  How do you expect to fit the entire graph (relationships especially) in 1k of memory?  If each relationship is 33 bytes, then each batch is ~3300 bytes, and doing that 1000 times you get an even bigger number. :) Unless I'm misreading something...

Comment: Also also, do the nodes exist beforehand? I.e. are you just inserting relationships? I can see you're using a START clause with a legacy index called "node" (at least that's what it looks like).  If you're using Neo4j 2.x, have you tried eliminating the START clause and using a CREATE/MERGE statement with labels instead?

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to show. I only gave the memory mapped buffer 1k bytes which means that it should NOT be able to keep all the nodes from the file buffer in memory. This should decrease the write performance as it will now have to start writing to disk. But there are no difference in performance when I put the memory mapped buffer to 1k or to 100MB, which I find is very odd.
I am not trying to optimize the script, I am just trying to see if there is a difference when using the buffer or not, and so far it seems like it completely ignoes the buffer and just uses the JVM heap.

Comment: Ok. As above, what kind of times are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

For your queries:

- Use Parameters!
- Use Labels & Indexes in 2.0.x
- Try not to use random in performance test loops
- Make sure to use streaming

Comment: I am running on Ubuntu 12.04. I have edited the post to add the logs